# Automated FSM for C

Tags: c, linux, finite-automata

I am looking for a automated finite state machine generator for C? I have seen a few over the internet but unable to decide which one to use. If anybody worked with any such tool then help me to find the right one.

Thanks,
Ravi Gupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) is fairly powerful.